# How to create data table in Cucumber feature file and step definition for my scenario

Tags: java, selenium, text, cucumber

Assume my condition in UI application, depends upon stage and status i need to validate Condition column.

Note:

- order will be rearranged
- data has to pass from cucumber feature file

How to write code in step definition?

```
SlNo Stage Status Condition
------------------------------
1     p      d       True
2     p      d1      True
3     p      r       True
4     p      r1      False
5     v1     f       True
6     v1     s       False
7     v1     c       True
8     v1     a       True
9     v1     a1      False
10     v2     f      True
11     v2     s      False
12    v2     c       True
```

Directly I have applied stage and status in step definition file by using if and elseif conditions

Output: I am getting correct, but I wanted to pass data by using Cucumber feature file to step definition.

**Note**: in UI data will be rearranged(it wont maintains the same order).

Examples:

```
  | slno |stage|Status|Condition|
  | 1    |p    |d     |True     |
  | 2    |p    |d1    |True     |
  | 3    |p    |r     |True     |
  | 4    |p    |r1    |False    |

if(Cucumber_p == (Cucumber_d||Cucumber_d1||Cucumber_r){
 sa.assertThat((boolean) Cucumber_Condition).isTrue();
}
else if(Cucumber_p == Cucumber_r1){
 sa.assertThat((boolean) Cucumber_Condition).isFalse();
}
else if(Cucumber_v1 == (Cucumber_f||Cucumber_c||Cucumber_a){
 sa.assertThat((Boolean) Cucumber_Condition).isTrue();
}
else if(Cucumber_v1 == (Cucumber_s||Cucumber_a1){
 sa.assertThat((boolean) Cucumber_Condition).isFalse();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .feature file you type (for example):

```
Given I have a table
|SlNo| Stage| Status| Condition|
| 1  |  p   |   d   |    True  |
...
(fyi, you may keep the header or skip)
```

Then, in the method you use DataTable:

```
@Given("I have a table)
public void workWithTable(DataTable dataTable) {
for (int i = 0; i <= datatable.height(); i++) /*if you have header, 
                                                    you start with 1*/
   string slNo = dataTable.cell(0, i);
   string stage = dataTable.cell(1, i);
   /* etc..., so you may build a List using these data or use the 
                info as you wish*/
}
```